# Force re-render D3 component on React after state change in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I have two react components (in typescript). In the first component I have some menus.

```
   <Menu.Item
      name="graph"
      active={activeItem === "graph"}
      onClick={this.handleItemClick}
    />
    <Menu.Item
      name="flow"
      active={activeItem === "flow"}
      onClick={this.handleItemClick}
    />
```

corresponding event handler

```
handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => {this.setState({ activeItem: name, hello: name, selection:name });};
```

In the render function I am passing this decision as a property to another react component D3Core

before return,

```
var child = this.state.selection==="graph"? true : false ;
```

inside return,

```
<D3Core renderfull = {child} width={this.state.width} height={this.state.height} data={data} />
```

In D3Core render function I am using the following to render the graph

```
if(this.props.renderfull) {
        return <div style={style} ref={mountPoint => (this.ctrls.mountPoint = mountPoint)} />;
    } else {
        return <p>Hello</p>;
    }
```

where the force layout d3 computation is done inside the componentDidMount callback.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { width, height, data } = this.props;
    const force = d3
      .forceSimulation()
      .nodes(data.nodes)
      .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-120))
      .force('link', d3.forceLink(data.links).distance(50))
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

const svg = d3
      .select(this.ctrls.mountPoint)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);
    ...
```

The problem I am facing is when I first load the document it shows the graph but if I navigate away from the menu and return to the menu it just loads the div not the graph. I guess I have to re-render the graph but how?

I am guessing this is because all the components are already rendered and the d3 computation is not happening at all. Should I do the computation inside render?

I have attached couple of screenshots. THe first screenshot shows the graph is rendered when the page is first loaded. THe second screenshot shows the graph is not rendered only the div element when I navigated away from graph menu and came back.

Edit 1: [Here](https://codeshare.io/5Xn9kE) is my d3 code

[image]
[image]

Comment: do you still have an SVG in the `div`, do you destruct the SVG when the component is hidden?

Comment: @rioV8 no I do not destruct that. I added my code in the post.

Comment: `var child = this.state.selection==="graph";` is enough, the expression is a boolean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume the problem is that when `renderfull` gets toggled off and back on again, React removes the old `div` from the document and adds a new one, and your D3 instance is still attached to the old (removed) div.  However, the D3Core component instance remains mounted the whole time, so you don't get a new `componentDidMount` callback.

The cleanest solution would be to move the D3 stuff to a subcomponent of `D3Core` (for example, suppose the subcomponent is named `D3Sub`) and have `D3Core`'s `render` method return `<D3Sub ...>` only if `renderfull` is true.  Then, when `renderfull` gets toggled off and back on again, the `D3Sub` instance will be destroyed and a new `D3Sub` instance will be created, and the new instance will get a `componentDidMount` callback.

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue. But as you said "React removes the old div from the document and adds a new one" should not the componentDidMount callback trigger again?

Comment: The `componentDidMount` callback on a given `D3Core` component instance is called only once, after that instance is fully initialized.  After that, the instance may re-render many times (resulting in addition and/or removal of DOM elements and subcomponents) and each time you will get a `componentDidUpdate`, not `componentDidMount`.  In principle, you could write `componentDidUpdate` to check if `renderfull` went from false to true and initialize another D3 instance if so, but using a subcomponent avoids duplicating code between `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: Will component did update be called before componentdidmount?

Comment: The first render of a component calls `componentDidMount` and not `componentDidUpdate`; see [this diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/).  If your question is about the order of `componentDidUpdate` of a parent component vs. `componentDidMount` of a child component that was just created when the parent re-rendered, I believe the `componentDidMount` of the child component comes first, but you could just try it and see.